Unable to find inverse Laplace transform of function MATLAB
I would like to take the inverse Laplace transform of the following:

The result after running z_use = ilapace(Z_use) is:

MATLAB is unable to take the full inverse Laplace transform. Is there something else I can do (different MATLAB method, use python, or literally anything to get the inverse Laplace transform), or is this function simply not solvable for an inverse Laplace transform?
